# Cannot detect firstVisibleItem on ListView if scrolled to fast

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a functionality that while scrolling, and if the `firstVisibleItem` of the listView is a header, then the page number (TextView) is increased to 1. In default, the page number is `Page 1 of 5`, `5` is total number of headers. Then if the user scrolls up, and if the header meet the top of the listView, the page number will be `Page 2 of 5`. The problem is, if it is scrolled too fast, the page number is not increasing, in short the `firstVisibleItem` is not detecting. Is there any other way to achieve this?

My header is like a simple list row only. I only changed the background color of that row (with a condition) to make it look like a header.

Thank you in advanced for all your help.

**Update**

Here is my `onScrollListener` where it detects the `firstVisibleItem`

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
     private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;

     @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) { }

     @Override
     public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

         if(mLastFirstVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem) {
             final MyModel item = adapter.getItem(mLastFirstVisibleItem);
             if (item != null) {
                 if (item.isHeader()) {
                     if (mLastFirstVisibleItem > 0) {
                         count++;
                         currentPage.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                     }
                 }
             }

         }

         if(mLastFirstVisibleItem > firstVisibleItem) {
             final MyModel item = adapter.getItem(mLastFirstVisibleItem);
             if (item != null) {
                 if (item.isHeader()) {
                     count--;
                     currentPage.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                 }
             }
         }
         mLastFirstVisibleItem=firstVisibleItem;

     }

  });
```

Comment: Would you mind share your codes here
"

Comment: @PartTimeNerd done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think their should be some condition for

```
if(mLastFirstVisibleItem <= firstVisibleItem) {
...
}
```

or

```
 if(mLastFirstVisibleItem >= firstVisibleItem) {
    ...
    }
```

because when both values will be same.. 
your if condition will be false at that time

instead of updating count variable everytime
you can Use combination of mLastFirstVisibleItem or adapter.getSize or count to show latest value
if both are same it would be last item

Comment: Thank you, but the problem still occurred when I scrolled too fast from my listView.